# Problem with the parameters while evaluating a Javascript function by string name

Tags: javascript, string, function, eval

I have a string `funcName` which contains the name of (an existing) javascript function. Additionally, I have a string `funcParams` which contains the list of parameters for the called function. I wish to run this function on these parameters. I use `eval(funcName)(funcParams)` in various places. The functions called can be different, and thus the amount of input parameters for each function differ.

For example, lets say I got:

```
var number = 5;
function succ(x) { return x+1;}
function average(x,y) {return (x+y)/2; }
```

I may have `funcName = "succ"` and `funcParams="3"`, in which case I want to apply `succ(3)`. But I might have `funcName = "average"` and `funcParams="3,5"`. In both cases `funcParams` will be a single string, but I want it to be a group of parameters. Should I try to define `funcParams` as an array? By using `.split(",")`? Or is there a better approach? I want to have a generic way to run the `funcName` on `funcParams`, regardless of the amount of parameters.

Another problem I have is that, for example, some of the parameters can be names of variables. For example, `funcParams="3,number"` and `funcName="average"`. Even if I solved my first issue and managed to seperate `3` and `number`, they are still treated as the string `"number"` instead of the variable named `number`. Any ideas how to address this issue as well?

I hope I managed to express myself clearly regarding these 2 issues.

Edit: anything inside `funcParams` which is not wrapped by `""` should not be automatically converted to a string. If `funcParams="5,"5",number"` then the first `5` should be an integer, the second `"5"` a string and the third `number` is a variable name.

Comment: So did you attempt to use eval()? Should be simple string concentration

Comment: regardless of what you do to funcParams, `eval` takes a string and evaluates it.  So you will need a string.  What's wrong with `eval(funcName + "(" + funcParams + ")");` ?

Comment: I would reconsider the approach--it looks like you're trying to build a generic expression handling system with the ability to add functions. IMO I'd just either (a) use an existing module like mathjs, or (b) duplicate that effort and write a simple expression parser, which is simpler than you might expect.

Comment: Thanks. I had a very silly syntax mistake. I used `eval(funcName)(funcParams);` instead of `eval(funcName + "(" + funcParams + ")");`.